# "this" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following:

```
function test() {
     this.message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object
     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', function(mouseEvent) {
         alert(this.message); // Incorrect as "this" refers to this.mypolygon
     });     
}
```

How do I make it such that I can correctly have "Hello World" be alerted within the event listener? In other words, get the correct context of "this from within the eventlistener?

Comment: `var message = "Hello World"; alert(message);` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a closure.

```
function test() {
     var self = this;
     this.message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object

     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', function(mouseEvent) {
         alert(self.message); // Now "self" points to parent function scope
     });     
}
```

Comment: You should not bind "this" because inside listener "this" refers to google.maps.Marker object and changing it could mess up the API behavior..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `this` keyword.  Use something else that doesn't get changed inside the `addListener`:

```
function test() {
     foo.message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object
     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', function(mouseEvent) {
         alert(foo.message); 
     });     
}
```

or even cleaner:

```
function test() {
     var message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object
     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', function(mouseEvent) {
         alert(message); 
     });     
}
```

alternatively, you could do:

```
function test() {
     this.message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object

     var self = this;
     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', function(mouseEvent) {
         alert(self.message); 
     });     
}
```

Lastly, if you really want to use `this` inside the click handler, you can use `bind`:

```
function test() {
     this.message = "Hello World";
     this.marker = //A google marker object

     google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', myFunc.bind(this) );

     function myFunc(mouseEvent) {
         alert(this.message); 
     }     
}
```

Comment: Doesnt appear to be working right. "foo is undefined". Assuming that test is an object, and that I am creating a new instance of test... doesnt appear to work.

Comment: Of course, if you haven't defined foo first, it will be `undefined`. It wasn't meant to be taken literally.  I just wanted to point out that you should not use `this` to attach `message` to, but any other (defined) object.  Or as I pointed out in my second version, just declare a new variable, i.e. `message`

Comment: The issue with that is that it is local to the function. If I had another function say: test.prototype.somefunctionwitheventlistener = function() {} then that function would not be able to see "message". Is there some way I could pass "this" to it?

Comment: OK, I just added another example.  If you really want to attach message to `this`, then you can do that, but you just need to make sure you assign `this` to an alias before you try to use it in the `addListener` (where `this` is in another scope)